# Line thickness in a canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I want to make lines with a thickness of 1px in a canvas element.

I can't seem to find an example that is correct though. I am currently using the method on this site https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_5_canvas_linewidth.html

In this example the line that should be 1px appears to actually be 2px but a lighter color. This is in both Chrome 10 and Firefox 4.

I would expect the width of that left most line to be the same as the one that is underlining the title on that page.

Is there another way to draw a line to get the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notice the part

> However, the leftmost and all other odd-integer-width thickness lines do not appear crisp, because of the path's positioning.

and

> Obtaining crisp lines requires
>   understanding how paths are stroked.
>   In the images below, the grid
>   represents the canvas coordinate grid.
>   The squares between gridlines are
>   actual on-screen pixels. In the first
>   grid image below, a rectangle from
>   (2,1) to (5,5) is filled. The entire
>   area between them (light red) falls on
>   pixel boundaries, so the resulting
>   filled rectangle will have crisp
>   edges.

So, if you draw at half pixels (*when drawing an odd pixel width line*) then the actual drawn edges will fall on absolute pixels and look fine..

example at http://jsfiddle.net/Wav5v/

---

Alternatively you can use the [`fillRect(x,y,width,height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Rectangles) with a width of 1..

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    ctx.fillRect(5 + i*14, 5, 1+i, 140); 
  }
}
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/Wav5v/1/

Comment: Do you know why this is so? This is incredibly odd.

Comment: WPF has the same issue and I guess for the same reason. Look at this MSDN article for some explaining: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem: all my lines were much larger than 1 px

Here is what I had before my solution:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"/>
<style type="text/css">
    #myCanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        width:1024px;
        height: 301px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        }​
</style>
```

Using CSS to set the canvas size.  My solution was to set the width and height of the canvas element in the html.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=1024 height=301>
```

and then all was OK.